# Objective-C difference between resolving events and actions

Tags: objective-c, events, delegates

Im new to Objective-C & iOS programming so Im very confused about event and action handling. I don't really understand what is the difference between connecting a button in Interface builder with its files owner method (for instance connecting button action pressed with my personal method buttonClicked) and on the other hand creating a delegate which will respond to button events? I am confused because I come from C# (.NET) and there you only handling events via delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create event handling programmatically first. Some assumptions ...

- you have class `MyViewController`
- this class does contain property `myButton` (`UIButton *`)
- you do want to handle events in this class

First step is to create method to handle your button taps:

```
-(void)onMyButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender {
  // My button was tapped, whoa, which one is in sender argument
}
```

Add tap event handling:

```
-(void)loadView {
  [super loadView];
  [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onMyButtonTap:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

What this code does? `self` in this case is instance of `MyViewController` class, which is going to handle touch up inside event (`addTarget`). `action` is method which will be called when `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` fires.

So the `addTarget:...` line adds event handling and when the control event fires, this ...

```
[self onMyButtonTap:self.myButton];
```

... will be called automatically.

It's simplified example, it can be more complicated in the real world:

- you can have `UIButton` in separate `UIView` (good practice, I dislike when people put them in `UIViewController`)
- you can handle multiple buttons taps in one method (distinguish between them by `sender` argument)
- you can create more tap handling methods, one method for one button,
- ...

And now back to outlets. Outlet is just an automatic glue for `addTarget:...`.

`UIButton` is subclass of `UIControl` and here you can see how other events can be handled and what events you can handle.

Delegation is also common practice, but not for `UIControl`. There's no delegate, etc. You have to do it in this way.

Or you can enhance `UIButton` to handle events via blocks for example. Here's one way https://gist.github.com/2468899 or you can Google for more.

Comment: @gGololicic The GUI designer in Visual Studio does generate actual source code that builds the GUI as designed and thus the GUI is set in stone at compile time. The GUI designer in XCode does NOT generate source code. Instead it generates a .nib (sometimes also called a .xib,) or, in the case of iOS 5 and up, a .storyboard. Nibs, xibs and storyboards can be thought of as metadata describing the GUI and from which the GUI is generated at runtime. It's sort of like a data-driven GUI.